# PowerShell locking File

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do something very simple in PowerShell.

1. Reading the contents of a file
2. Manipulation some string
3. Saving the modified test back to the file

   ```
   function Replace {
     $file = Get-Content C:\Path\File.cs
     $file | foreach {$_ -replace "document.getElementById", "$"} |out-file -filepath C:\Path\File.cs
   }
   ```

I have tried `Set-Content` as well.

I always get unauthorized exception. I can see the `$file` has the file content, error is coming while writing the file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this fail for all files or just that one or in that path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely caused by the `Get-Content` cmdlet that gets a lock for reading and `Out-File` that tries to get its lock for writing. Similar question is here: [Powershell: how do you read & write I/O within one pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035026/powershell-how-do-you-read-write-i-o-within-one-pipeline)

So the solution would be:

```
${C:\Path\File.cs} = ${C:\Path\File.cs} | foreach {$_ -replace "document.getElementById", '$'}
${C:\Path\File.cs} = Get-Content C:\Path\File.cs | foreach {$_ -replace  "document.getElementById", '$'}

$content = Get-Content C:\Path\File.cs | foreach {$_ -replace "document.getElementById", '$'}
$content | Set-Content C:\Path\File.cs
```

Basically you need to buffer the content of the file so that the file can be closed (`Get-Content` for reading) and after that the buffer should be flushed to the file (`Set-Content`, during that write lock will be required).

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Now I feel stupid for asking this  :) but thanks.

I did read about this but since I was piping everything in one statement it gave me error as the lock was not released.

Cool!!

Comment: I don't understand the solution -  I have an xml file via `[xml]$file = Get-Content $filename`  and when I attempt to delete the file after read it, I get the locking error. There's no dispose method on the `XmlDocument` and nulling `$file` doesn't work, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe the variable should be 'xml' `[xml]$xml = Get-Content $filename`. So  it's clear, that it's not file, but object that represents xml. `Remove-Item $filename` deletes the file.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer worked for me if I had a single file operation, but when I did multiple Set-Content or Add-Content operations on the same file, I still got the "is being used by another process" error.

In the end I had to write to a temp file, then copy the temp file to the original file:

```
(Get-Content C:\Path\File.cs) | foreach {$_ -replace "document.getElementById", '$'} | Set-Content C:\Path\File.cs.temp
Copy-Item C:\Path\File.cs.temp C:\Path\File.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

Personal experience: I had the "locked file syndrome" in one of my procedures. I found it was caused by a New-Object assignment on the file. I realised that I had not issued a "Dispose()" call on the object. I rewrote the offending code to dispose of the 'New-Object' as soon as convenient and the "locked file" syndrome was resolved.
A learning event for me = always dispose of each New-Object!